# Ionic 2 Livereload

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

When developing with Ionic 2 how does one stay on the current page when making code changes? In Ionic 1 livereload would take you back to your current url - however in ionic 2 there are no urls.

Is there a setting that will make livereload keep me on the current page?

I'm open to enabling URLs as well if that's what it takes to not have to manually navigate back to my page on every code change. However I haven't been able to find how to do that in the v2 docs yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `this.rootPage` in your `app.component.ts` to the page you are working on. I often do this if i am working on say the `foobar.ts` page for a while ill change it to

```
this.rootPage = FooBar;
```

And then change it back to the default root page when i am done.

Comment: This is what I end up doing now as well.

Answer (score 3):

To stop live reloading in Ionic2 following changes I have done in the configurations file : `ionic.config.js`.

In `ionic.config.js`

```
watch: {
  sass: ['app/**/*.scss'],
  html: ['app/**/*.html'],
  livereload: [
    'www/build/**/*.html',
    'www/build/**/*.js',
    'www/build/**/*.css'
  ]
}
```

above section edited to :

```
watch: {
  sass: ['app/**/*.scss'],
  html: ['app/**/*.html'],
}
```

Then stopped `ionic serve` by `q`, and again started. Auto refreshing got stopped, we have to manually refresh to reflect the latest changes.

Comment: this is not what the OP asked

Answer (score 1):

Actually `ionic.config.js` has been deprecated . So i found a way may , go to this `node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\config`  . Change in file called `watch.js`

```
srcFiles: {
    paths: ['{{SRC}}/**/*.(ts|html|s(c|a)ss)'],
    options: { ignored: ['{{SRC}}/**/*.spec.ts', '{{SRC}}/**/*.e2e.ts', '**/*.DS_Store'] },
    callback: watch.buildUpdate
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to do what you are asking for, because ionic 2 is not using urls. Actually they are handling the pages as a variable on window, so when you or the live reload refresh the page it will go to the initial state. By the way actually there are no plans for implement the angular router, let's wait until the RC, maybe they would like to implement it

Comment: Your answer is outdated. Ionic supports Deeplinking atm.